# Issue with Tabs and JS Smooth Scroll (Two Clicks)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched on stackoverflow a bit and couldn't find an exact answer to this problem.

I have some tabs on my webpage. I want when a user clicks a tab to place an active tag on the tab the user picked and then scroll to the first anchor (anchors placed before the first paragraph usually).

So far, it is working with the code below, with the exception that the user must click the tab twice to make it the active tab and then to scroll. Is there a way so that on ONE click, the tab selected is marked as active and it scrolls to the anchor on the tab? I am a bit new to JS so I apologize if this is an easy answer. I appreciate all help and if you want an example of the tabs and having to click twice, please visit [my website](http://firesuppressiontech.com/heated-sample-lines/).

JS Tabs

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("ul#tabs li").click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        var tabNum = $(this).index();
        var nthChild = tabNum + 1;
        $("ul#tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("ul#tab li.active").removeClass("active");
        $("ul#tab li:nth-child(" + nthChild + ")").addClass("active");
    }
});
});
```

JS Smooth Scroll

```
;
(function ($) {
var h = $.scrollTo = function (a, b, c) {
    $(window).scrollTo(a, b, c)
};
h.defaults = {
    axis: 'xy',
    duration: parseFloat($.fn.jquery) >= 1.3 ? 0 : 1,
    limit: true
};
h.window = function (a) {
    return $(window)._scrollable()
};
$.fn._scrollable = function () {
    return this.map(function () {
        var a = this,
            isWin = !a.nodeName || $.inArray(a.nodeName.toLowerCase(), ['iframe', '#document', 'html', 'body']) != -1;
        if (!isWin) return a;
        var b = (a.contentWindow || a).document || a.ownerDocument || a;
        return /webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || b.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ? b.body : b.documentElement
    })
};
$.fn.scrollTo = function (e, f, g) {
    if (typeof f == 'object') {
        g = f;
        f = 0
    }
    if (typeof g == 'function') g = {
        onAfter: g
    };
    if (e == 'max') e = 9e9;
    g = $.extend({}, h.defaults, g);
    f = f || g.duration;
    g.queue = g.queue && g.axis.length > 1;
    if (g.queue) f /= 2;
    g.offset = both(g.offset);
    g.over = both(g.over);
    return this._scrollable().each(function () {
        if (e == null) return;
        var d = this,
            $elem = $(d),
            targ = e,
            toff, attr = {}, win = $elem.is('html,body');
        switch (typeof targ) {
            case 'number':
            case 'string':
                if (/^([+-]=)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?$/.test(targ)) {
                    targ = both(targ);
                    break
                }
                targ = $(targ, this);
                if (!targ.length) return;
            case 'object':
                if (targ.is || targ.style) toff = (targ = $(targ)).offset()
        }
        $.each(g.axis.split(''), function (i, a) {
            var b = a == 'x' ? 'Left' : 'Top',
                pos = b.toLowerCase(),
                key = 'scroll' + b,
                old = d[key],
                max = h.max(d, a);
            if (toff) {
                attr[key] = toff[pos] + (win ? 0 : old - $elem.offset()[pos]);
                if (g.margin) {
                    attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('margin' + b)) || 0;
                    attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('border' + b + 'Width')) || 0
                }
                attr[key] += g.offset[pos] || 0;
                if (g.over[pos]) attr[key] += targ[a == 'x' ? 'width' : 'height']() * g.over[pos]
            } else {
                var c = targ[pos];
                attr[key] = c.slice && c.slice(-1) == '%' ? parseFloat(c) / 100 * max : c
            }
            if (g.limit && /^\d+$/.test(attr[key])) attr[key] = attr[key] <= 0 ? 0 : Math.min(attr[key], max);
            if (!i && g.queue) {
                if (old != attr[key]) animate(g.onAfterFirst);
                delete attr[key]
            }
        });
        animate(g.onAfter);

        function animate(a) {
            $elem.animate(attr, f, g.easing, a && function () {
                a.call(this, e, g)
            })
        }
    }).end()
};
h.max = function (a, b) {
    var c = b == 'x' ? 'Width' : 'Height',
        scroll = 'scroll' + c;
    if (!$(a).is('html,body')) return a[scroll] - $(a)[c.toLowerCase()]();
    var d = 'client' + c,
        html = a.ownerDocument.documentElement,
        body = a.ownerDocument.body;
    return Math.max(html[scroll], body[scroll]) - Math.min(html[d], body[d])
};

function both(a) {
    return typeof a == 'object' ? a : {
        top: a,
        left: a
    }
}
    })(jQuery);

    ;
    (function (b) {
function g(a, e, d) {
    var h = e.hash.slice(1),
        f = document.getElementById(h) || document.getElementsByName(h)[0];
    if (f) {
        a && a.preventDefault();
        var c = b(d.target);
        if (!(d.lock && c.is(":animated") || d.onBefore && !1 === d.onBefore(a, f, c))) {
            d.stop && c._scrollable().stop(!0);
            if (d.hash) {
                var a = f.id == h ? "id" : "name",
                    g = b("<a> </a>").attr(a, h).css({
                        position: "absolute",
                        top: b(window).scrollTop(),
                        left: b(window).scrollLeft()
                    });
                f[a] = "";
                b("body").prepend(g);
                location = e.hash;
                g.remove();
                f[a] = h
            }
            c.scrollTo(f, d).trigger("notify.serialScroll", [f])
        }
    }
}
var i = location.href.replace(/#.*/, ""),
    c = b.localScroll = function (a) {
        b("body").localScroll(a)
    };
c.defaults = {
    duration: 1E3,
    axis: "y",
    event: "click",
    stop: !0,
    target: window,
    reset: !0
};
c.hash = function (a) {
    if (location.hash) {
        a = b.extend({}, c.defaults, a);
        a.hash = !1;
        if (a.reset) {
            var e = a.duration;
            delete a.duration;
            b(a.target).scrollTo(0, a);
            a.duration = e
        }
        g(0, location, a)
    }
};
b.fn.localScroll = function (a) {
    function e() {
        return !!this.href && !! this.hash && this.href.replace(this.hash, "") == i && (!a.filter || b(this).is(a.filter))
    }
    a = b.extend({}, c.defaults, a);
    return a.lazy ? this.bind(a.event, function (d) {
        var c = b([d.target, d.target.parentNode]).filter(e)[0];
        c && g(d, c, a)
    }) : this.find("a,area").filter(e).bind(a.event, function (b) {
        g(b, this, a)
    }).end().end()
}
    })(jQuery);

     // Initialize all .smoothScroll links
    jQuery(function ($) {
$.localScroll({
    filter: '.smoothScroll'
});
     });
```

HTML

```
<ul id="tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#features" class="smoothScroll">FEATURES</a></li>
<li><a href="#specs" class="smoothScroll">SPECIFICATIONS</a></li>
<li><a href="#config" class="smoothScroll">COMPARE CONFIGURATIONS</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="tab">
<li class="active">
    <a name="features"></a>Content 1
</li>
<li>
    <a name="specs"></a>Content 2
</li>
  <li>
    <a name="config"></a>Content 3
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#features" class="smoothScroll">FEATURES</a></li>
<li><a href="#specs" class="smoothScroll">SPECIFICATIONS</a></li>
<li><a href="#config" class="smoothScroll">COMPARE CONFIGURATIONS</a></li>
</ul>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<ul id="tab">
<li class="active">
    <a name="features"></a>Content 1
</li>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<li>
    <a name="specs"></a>Content 2
</li>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <li>
    <a name="config"></a>Content 3
</li>
```

To scroll to the specific anchor you can use the following, I am not sure why you have such a long script?

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehj8naq6/1/)
[JSFiddle This should give you something to work with](http://jsfiddle.net/ehj8naq6/3/)

Comment: @hjardline I appreciate the help! The long code allows for the smooth scroll though. The code you provided doesn't scroll to the anchor in a smooth fashion (That is more of my own design wants than a bash at your code because it works perfect). Also, I still have to click my tab twice for it to make the tab active and smooth scroll. Is there a way to condense this into one click? GoPro is a good example when you click the tab, it makes it active and scrolls to the anchor: http://shop.gopro.com/cameras/heroplus-lcd/CHDHB-101.html#/tab1

Comment: @FlexMarket You have to click 'Run' at the top of the JSFiddle page for the JQuery to be active, it does have smooth scroll

Comment: Thank you! It does work with the fiddle. However, when I added it to my website, it loses the smooth scroll and just goes to the anchor. It can be seen here: http://www.firesuppressiontech.com/heated-sample-lines

Comment: After messing around with it, the smooth scroll still does not happen with the new fiddle (JSFiddle This should give you something to work with). Any idea how to get the smooth scroll to work?